# why flutter run not working on manjaro linux?

Tags: flutter, manjaro

I'm running flutter 3.0.0

> `$ flutter run -d linux or flutter run`

Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
CMake Error at /var/lib/snapd/snap/flutter/111/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
The C++ compiler

```
"/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTC_8627d"
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8627d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_8627d
FAILED: cmTC_8627d 
: && /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++    -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -lpthread -ldl -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -lpthread -ldl -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ CMakeFiles/cmTC_8627d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_8627d   && :
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/crtbegin.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/crtbegin.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/crtend.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/crtend.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libgpg-error.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libgpg-error.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libgpg-error.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libgpg-error.so.0: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
//lib64/libgpg-error.so.0: undefined reference to `__libc_single_threaded@GLIBC_2.32'
//lib64/libgpg-error.so.0: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock@GLIBC_2.34'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

Building Linux application...
Exception: Unable to generate build files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

From discussions on [this Github issue](https://github.com/canonical/flutter-snap/issues/45), it looks like the issue might boil down to the libraries shipped with the snap itself.

I managed to get it running on Manjaro (had the same issue as you) by switching to edge and rebuilding the app from scratch:

```
# Switch to the edge channel instead of stable
snap refresh flutter --edge

# Clean out the current build dir.
rm -rf ./build

# Try running again
flutter run -d linux
```

The edge channel probably isn't a good choice for production code, but if you just wanted to dive in to get a feel for the Linux mode, it should probably be fine :)